# Set Values From Environment Variables at Compile Time

Tags: c#, .net

I need to include what is effectively an API key in a dll, without that API key making it into my team's version control. I acknowledge that the string will be decompilable from the dll, but that is not really a concern, as this is for an internal tool.

Currently, I have added a `.resx` file to the `.csproj` file which includes the API key. This is excluded from version control via the `.gitignore` explicitly. However, I do not want to rely on `.gitignore` as a security measure.

What I would like to be able to do is read the environment variables at compile time and inject the correct value into a `const` property or something.

Is there an accepted way to do this in .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish your goal of using environment variables might be to add a pre-build step that runs a script to write an environment variable to a file, for example:

**Pre-build step:**

```
echo namespace Foo ^{ public class Bar ^{ public const string Key = ^"%secretkey%^"^;^}^} > "$(ProjectDir)test.cs"
```

then a post-build step that sanitizes that file:

**Post-build step**

```
echo namespace Foo ^{ public class Bar ^{ public const string Key = ^"*****^"^;^}^} > "$(ProjectDir)test.cs"
```

I'd still put `test.cs` in `.gitignore` in case something failed.

Comment: Seems a lot safer to have the DLL read the API key from the environment.

Comment: I agree, it would be safer to read it at run-time.  However the question is asking how to make an environment variable available at *compile-time*.  Distributing a key embedded in the assembly is arguably as risky or possibly riskier than putting it in source code control. My answer does not address risk as the OP seems aware of the risks already.

Comment: The key can't be read from the environment as this is being deployed to user machines (again, only internally) and not being run on my machine. I'll accept this answer as the solution. It would be nice if MSBuild supported this idea somehow...